# Identity management framework in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

A new application is being built with an Angular Client and a ASP.Net Web API back end.  The back end will be consumed by the Angular Client only in the short term (1 year), but will be consumed externally (mobile and 3rd parties) in the long run.

What are the pros and cons of using ASP.NET Identity vs IdentityServer4 initially in securing the API?  How difficult will it be to switch over to IdentityServer from ASP.NET Identity down the road and is it worth the effort of using IdentityServer from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity is a user store, with some helper libraries that enable cookie authentication on top of it. Using ASP.NET Identity to protect HTTP APIs is not what it was designed for.

IdentityServer 4 is an OAuth & OpenID Connect authorization server. Using IdentityServer to protect HTTP APIs is exactly what it was designed for.

Comment: And indeed you can integrate ASP.Net Identity (the user store/services) and IDS4 (the token service) and get a LOT of stuff for free.